# Can HTML markup tags interleave?

Tags: html

I suspect this is invalid html but I'm chiefly interested to know whether browsers will handle it gracefully.  I want to <mark> some text that may have html tags interspersed.  Specifically, if a mark tag opens after another formatting tag, say span or font, but the span/font closes before the mark closes, will (modern) browsers handle it gracefully?

```
<span><mark>text</span> more text</mark>
```

Comment: No, not really.  I wouldn't recommend or count on browsers "knowing" what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span><mark>text</span> more text</mark>` is **invalid HTML**, which can be confirmed by the **[W3 Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/check)**.

Browsers cannot be relied upon to handle invalid markup reliably. In the above, `<mark>` will mark the first `text`. Then `</span>` will kick in and close the first `<span>`, and the parser will get confused as to how to handle the open `<mark>`. In most cases, your ending `</mark>` tag will be interpreted as invalid, because the parser will think that the tag is not open.

Here's an example with `<p>` and `<a>`:

```html
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google 1</p>Google 2</a>
```

Note that the two lines are split, indicating that the `<p>` tag triggered, though **both** lines take the hyperlink.

As for your mention of the `<font>` tag, please note that this is [**obsolete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), and you should be controlling the fonts via CSS instead.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: The W3 Validation Service complains: "Sorry! This document cannot be checked.".